# SharePoint Online External Sharing Feature - Available through API?

Tags: web-services, client-object-model, sharepoint-online

I have a case where we would like to create a web part for use in SharePoint Online where users can request to share a site with an external vendor. We would like to automate the process of Sharing to External users. Can anyone tell me if this capability is available via APIs or web services?

Comment: A tip (rather than an answer): I'd check out the source code in http://anonymous365.codeplex.com/. That should give you some starting points.